# select data in a column of a pandas dataframe depending on pieces of string in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with column 'a' which is a list of kids and column 'b' which is the number of toys for each kid

```
dic = { 'a': [ 'pippo', 'giovanni', 'giacomo', 'giovanni', 'giovanni', 'pippo'],\
           'b': [ 3, 5, 1, 10, 7, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

The dataframe is

```
    a           b
0   pippo       3
1   giovanni    5
2   giacomo     1
3   giovanni    10
4   giovanni    7
5   pippo       8
```

In this case some of the kids are repeted over the dataframe, if I want to know how many toys has giovanni, than I just have to write this

```
df['b'][ df['a'] == 'giovanni' ]


1   5
3   10
4   7
```

The sum of of the numbers on the second column are the number of toys that giovanni has ( 5 + 10 + 7 = 22).

But how can I figure out the number of toys owned by giovanni if the last two letters of his name are not properly written? Here the situation

```
dic = { 'a': [ 'pippo', 'giovanLi', 'giacomo', 'giovanNi', 'giovanMi', 'pippo'],\
           'b': [ 3, 5, 1, 10, 7, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

the dataframe is

```
    a           b
0   pippo       3
1   giovanLi    5
2   giacomo     1
3   giovanNi    10
4   giovanMi    7
5   pippo       8
```

I would like something like this

```
df['b'][ df['a'][:-2] == 'giovan'  ]
```

that select all the numbers of toys from the fact that in column b there is a string that starts with 'giovan'.

What do you suggest me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two alternatives:

```
df.loc[df['a'].str.startswith('giovan'), 'b'].sum()
Out: 22

df.groupby(df['a'].str[:-2])['b'].sum()
Out: 
a
giaco      1
giovan    22
pip       11
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

The first one uses the `startswith`  method. The second one groups the name column by the first `n-2`  characters. In general, you need the `str`  accessor for these operations. Your method would have worked if you tried `df['b'][df['a'].str[:-2] == 'giovan']`. This is called chained indexing though, I'd suggest using `.loc`.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to think a bit broader and remove case insensitivity altogether that and allow matching across any type of substring rather than only 2 characters from the end missing. Below should do what you are after and be a bit more inclusive to compensate for inaccuracies in the data.

```
df[df['a'].str.contains('giovanni', flags=re.IGNORECASE)]['b'].sum()
```

It creates a boolean selection by checking for the substring you want to identify with case insensitive properties, then it returns only the 'b' column so you have a series that you can then sum the result of.